# Conditional formatting of cell in each row by using macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, conditional-formatting

I have a excel table consisting of 500+ rows with column headers.

I need help in writing conditional formatting macro such that in a row `A2:L2` if any cell value is not equal to cell value `M2` then highlight that cell.
i.e.

- if ($A2:$L2) <> $M2 --> then highlight those cells in this row
- if ($A3:$L3) <> $M3 --> then highlight those cells in this row
- if ($A4:$L4) <> $M4 --> then highlight those cells in this row
- if ($A5:$L5) <> $M5 --> then highlight those cells in this row
  .
  .
  .
- if ($A500:$L500) <> $M500 --> then highlight those cells in this row

Sample table

> COL-1 COL-2   COL-3   COL-4   COL-5   COL-6   COL-7   COL-8   COL-9   COL-10  COL-11  COL-12  COL-13
>
> val-13    val-13  val-13  val-13  **val-17**  **val-18**  val-13  **val-20**  val-13  val-13  val-13  **val-24**  val-13
>
> val-26    **val-15**  val-26  **val-17**  val-26  **val-19**  val-26  val-26  val-26  **val-23**  val-26  val-26  val-26
>
> **val-27**    val-39  **val-29**  val-39  **val-31**  val-39  **val-33**  val-39  **val-35**  val-39  val-39  val-39  val-39

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without a macro.

In CELL A2, create a conditional format rule.

USE: `=A2<>$M2` as the rule,

Set your highlighting etc.

Then apply this to `=$A$2:$L$500`

Change the 500 if you want it to go further than 500 rows etc.

[image]